# Calling Functions based on the result of another function(Kafka)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have functions 
A , B & C
When I call function A() , this will send a kafka notif and once the notif is processed and the response is sent back, I need to call function B() and again this will send a kafka notif and so on and then once it's processed we need to call C().

Is there a way we can implement this apart from Calling B() in A()'s handle response?

For Example :

```
Sub Project Service has 
Class TestService
{
    function A()
     {
        Call Kafka Producer From SubProject KafkaProducer()
     }

function B()
     {
          Call Kafka Producer From SubProject KafkaProducer()
     }

}


Sub Project "KafkaService" has 
Class KafkaSvc
{
    @KafkaListener
    Process KafkaMessage()
    {
       Process Kafka Message and send back result to ReceivedResult.

    }
}


Sub Project "ReceivedResult" has

Class KafkaReceive
{

    @KafkaListener
    process KafkaMessageReceived()
    {
       Once it's processed here, B() has to be triggered
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try explaining with an example? so you mean there is a dependency on each function result?

Comment: @Deadpool I've updated the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: still i'm sorry it is not clear